# Linux Shell: combine two string from files, if there is same word in a string

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Small question, but hard for me. I have two files.
File A:

```
www.def.aBc.com
123.aaa.cOm
555.bbb.com.hk
www.fwe.wef.CcC.hk
www.abc.com
555.hjr.bbb.cOm.hk
www.ccc.hk
www.def.Abc.coM
123.aaa.COM
555.bbb.com.Hk
www.fwe.wef.cCc.hk
www.aBc.com
555.hjr.bbb.com.hK
www.ccc.hk
```

File B:

```
aaa.com
abc.com
bbb.com.hk
ccc.hk
```

I tried to attach File B to File A if match the end of word(don't care capitalization).
Output like this:

```
www.def.aBc.com  abc.com
123.aaa.cOm  aaa.com
555.bbb.com.hk  bbb.com.hk
www.fwe.wef.CcC.hk  ccc.hk
www.abc.com  abc.com
555.hjr.bbb.cOm.hk  bbb.com.hk
www.ccc.hk  ccc.hk
www.def.Abc.coM  abc.com
123.aaa.COM  aaa.com
555.bbb.com.Hk  bbb.com.hk
www.fwe.wef.cCc.hk  ccc.hk
www.aBc.com  abc.com
555.hjr.bbb.com.hK  bbb.com.hk
www.ccc.hk  ccc.hk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{for(x in a){if(index(tolower($0),x)>0)print $0,x}}' fileb filea
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{for(x in a){if(index(tolower($0),x)>0)print $0,x}}' fb fa
www.def.aBc.com abc.com
123.aaa.cOm aaa.com
555.bbb.com.hk bbb.com.hk
www.fwe.wef.CcC.hk ccc.hk
www.abc.com abc.com
555.hjr.bbb.cOm.hk bbb.com.hk
www.ccc.hk ccc.hk
www.def.Abc.coM abc.com
123.aaa.COM aaa.com
555.bbb.com.Hk bbb.com.hk
www.fwe.wef.cCc.hk ccc.hk
www.aBc.com abc.com
555.hjr.bbb.com.hK bbb.com.hk
www.ccc.hk ccc.hk
```

Comment: Thanks for helping on this. It is work for me. also learn alots

Comment: @Tazugan You're welcome. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` too.

```
for line in `cat file_b`; 
do 
  sed -i -r "s/(^.*$line$)/\1 $line/Ig" file_a; 
done
```

Comment: You can also skip the -i option and redirect it to a new file, depending on what you prefer

Answer (score 1):

Try this script which will store the result of the fusion in the file `fusion_result`:

```
if [[ -e fusion_result ]]
then
    rm fusion_result
fi

for linea in `cat A`
    do
    compare=`echo $linea | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` # Case insensitive
    for lineb in `cat B`
        do
        if [[ $compare =~ $lineb ]] # Regex comparison
            then
            echo $linea $lineb >> fusion_result
        fi
    done
done
```

If the lines in b are redundant (ie you have aaa.com and aaa.com.hk), change `$lineb` in the if statement to `$lineb$`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for (i in a) if ($1~i) print $0,i}' fileB fileA
```

#### Explanation

- `IGNORECASE=1` Case insensitive